# How to show DataFrame on listbox

Tags: python

I read excel file by pandas and need to load DataFrame to listbox, I already tried to do it but listbox can only show head of excel, not all of the data

Comment: There's not NEARLY enough information here.  You need to show us your code.  Which UI library are you using?  How did you create the listbox?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.